# Sticky chat box with new version of ember js

Tags: ember.js, chat, viewport

I am trying to build a chat with new version of ember js  and had a issue with scroll bar On chat body basically what I need is
When the user is scrolled to the bottom, new messages should show up. If they scroll up to read old messages, the chat to stay still. how to get this scenario can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you'd like to load more data whenever the user scrolls down to the bottom of the screen.  In Ember Octane the best way to handle this is with [a modifier](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/template-lifecycle-dom-and-modifiers/#toc_abstracting-the-logic-into-a-custom-modifier). You can write one yourself, but there is a very good [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-in-viewport) that [provides this for you](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-in-viewport#modifiers)

After doing `npm install ember-in-viewport` and restarting your ember development server. You can create a component with a list of the chats

```html
<ul id="messages">
  {{#each this.messages as |message|}}
    <li>{{message.txt}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  <div {{in-viewport onEnter=this.startLoading onExit=this.stopLoading scrollableArea="#messages"}}></div>
</ul>
```

Whenever that last `div` enters the users screen it will call `startLoading` in which you can poll for new messages and update the `messages` propert, but whenever that `div` isn't leaves the users viewport it will call `stopLoading` which can turn off the poll until the user reaches the end of the list again.

Comment: Hi John,
I tried to use it and in startLoading method i am giving logic as 'scrollTop = scroll Height' but its not at all triggering startLoading method

Comment: You'll need to post some code for more help with the details. https://ember-twiddle.com/ is the best place to create a working example to show what isn't working.

Comment: I added code  its not working but it gives generic idea
https://ember-twiddle.com/5d16a822a38712654f89774de6ebd4ee

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to do now. You want the list to scroll along with new messages added as they are added. I was worried about the data loading itself. Sorry. My answer won't help.